# How to connect Trino to Iceberg on MinIO storage?

Tags: minio, trino, apache-iceberg

I can't connect Trino to my Iceberg running on MinIO storage. Since MinIO is exposing S3 API i figured AWS Glue connector should work here, but maybe I'm wrong. Also tried REST connector and it was sending wrong requests (URI path was not S3 compatible I guess).

Can someone confirm/deny that glue connector should be used to connect to any S3 compatible storage, or does it work explicitly with AWS Glue services?

My connector properties:

```
connector.name=iceberg
iceberg.catalog.type=glue
hive.metastore.glue.endpoint-url=http://svc.cluster.local:9000
hive.metastore.glue.region=us-east-1
hive.metastore.glue.default-warehouse-dir=s3a://mzz/csv
```

MinIO is running at "http://svc.cluster.local:9000". I can add that I'm using Apache Spark to load data to MinIO (Iceberg format) and it is connecting without any issues.

Error message from Trino GUI:

> com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.AWSGlueException: null (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: null; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Comment: S3A connector works with minio; you'll need to switch to "path style access" and play with other things.

Answer (score 0):

Iceberg requires a metadata storage catalog. The data in the files itself is not enough. Trino supports a number of different metastores including Hive metastore, Glue and others.

Once you have a metastore running (maybe even same HMS you use from Spark) it will work just fine.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/iceberg.html#requirements) and an [example mini project](https://github.com/bitsondatadev/trino-getting-started/tree/main/iceberg/trino-iceberg-minio) for more info.

Comment: Is it possible to use Trino with MinIO without additional hive-metastore (thrift://...)?

Currently both my Iceberg data and metadata are stored in the same place (MinIO) and it would be perfect to keep it that way.